# Proving the Trichotomy Property

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis, proof-writing

I need to show that if $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, then only one of the following holds: $a\in \mathbb{P}, -a\in \mathbb{P}$, or $a=0.$

By a definition in my book, if $a-b \in \mathbb{P}$, then $a>b$; and if $a-b\in\mathbb{P}\cup {\{0\}}$, then $a\geq b$.

I was going to try to set $b=0$ and use that to show that $a-0\in \mathbb{P}$ so $a\in \mathbb{P}$, meaning $a>0$.
Then $b-a = 0-a=-a\in \mathbb{P}$, meaning $a<0$.
Then $b-a=0$, meaning $a=b=0$.
Since you can't have both $a>0$, $a<0$, and $a=0$, then you can only have one of the following: $a\in \mathbb{P}, -a\in \mathbb{P}$, or $a=0.$

However I'm not sure if this is rigorous enough (note: I am taking an intro analysis course). For one, am I just allowed to set $b=0$ to make these conclusions? Next, can I just say that $b-a=0$  rather than saying that if $a-b\in\mathbb{P}\cup {\{0\}}$ and $b-a\in\mathbb{P}\cup {\{0\}}$ then $a\geq b$ and $b\geq a$ so $a=b=0$? (The above just seems easier/simpler.) Finally, for that last line, I'm not sure how I "know" that I "can't have both $a>0$, $a<0$, and $a=0$", as in if this is trivial or if it comes from a theorem (I couldn't find one in the book).

Comment: What book are you using? The answer to this question will depend on the specific order in which the theory is presented.

Comment: Introduction to Real Analysis by Bartle and Sherbert. First they covered the algebraic properties of $\mathbb{R}$ (what makes a field), then the Order Properties of  $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @David Perhaps the well known text by Bartle.

Comment: Is this an exercise in the book? Where?

Comment: Have you taken an "introduction to higher mathematics" type course yet? Some colleges skip this and really shouldn't. I  just ask since if you haven't yet it will really help if you could even skim through a book on mathematical proofs. The questions you have asked are well addressed by such a book.

Comment: @David This is not an exercise in the book. However my homework says to prove it for a subset K of $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $K:=\{s+t\sqrt2:s,t\in\mathbb{Q}\}$.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean a "how to write proofs" course? I took one last term and it was a prerequisite for this class.

Comment: Also, please give more details. You should specify by $\mathbb{P}$ you mean the class of positive elements of the complete ordered field $\mathbb{R}$. To prove set membership we need too determine how to qualify elements for membership. So in the book they will have defined what $\mathbb{P}$ is.

Comment: So you are supposed to prove that there exists a subset $\mathbb{P}_K$ of $K$ that plays the same role for $K$ that $\mathbb{P}$ does for $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e., satisfies the same axioms). Is that right?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}$ is indeed the set of positive real numbers.

Comment: @David I think so. But I'm not sure if this question is just "supposed to be" Exercise 9 on page 31 mentioned below or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew said in his answer, based on the approach taken on your book, you cannot *prove* these properties of $\mathbb{P}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. The existence of $\mathbb{P} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the three order axioms is one of the basic properties of $\mathbb{R}$.

What you are apparently being asked to do here is to prove that for the field $K$ there exists a set $\mathbb{P}_K$ of numbers, which will be called the "positive elements of $K$," that makes $K$ into an ordered field. In fact, the exercise in the book tells you the order on $K$ should be the "order inherited from $\mathbb{R}$," which means that you should call an element of $K$ positive precisely when it is positive considered as a real number.

Therefore, define the set $\mathbb{P}_K$ to be $K \cap \mathbb{P}$. Then prove that $\mathbb{P}_K$ has the three required properties to play the role of a set of positive numbers for $K$. (Since your main problem seems to have been knowing what you needed to prove, I'll omit the proof, which is easy.)

Once these properties have been proved, for all $a, b \in K$ you define $b <_K a$ to mean $a - b \in \mathbb{P}_K$. It is easy to see that $b <_K a$ if and only if $ b < a$, so the subscript $K$ can be dropped. In other words, of $a$ and $b$, the larger number in $K$ is the same as the larger number in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Bartle and Sherbert *define* $\mathbb{P}$ as a set possessing three properties, one of which is the Trichotomy Property (p. 26). Therefore, $\mathbb{P}$ possesses the Trichotomy Property *by definition*.

Comment: This is a good answer to the question as stated. However, if you look at the comments, you'll see that Ted Desmond has something else in mind.

Comment: I am replying here as I lack the reputation to comment on other people's posts. Exercise 9 on page 31 asks the reader to show that $K := \{ s + t \sqrt{2} : s,t \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ satisfies the following properties: a) closure under addition and multiplication and b) the existence of multiplicative inverses. No other exercise makes reference to the set $K$. Either Ted Desmond misunderstood the question or his homework goes beyond the exercises in the text. I would ask for clarification of which.

Comment: Presumably, he would like to prove that $K$ is an ordered field.

Comment: @Andrew My homework just says that for $K:=\{s+t\sqrt2:s,t\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ prove that $K$ has the ordering properties defined on Section 2.1.5 of the book.